# Is a semicolon prohibited after NAME in `for NAME do ...`?

Tags: shell, posix, language-lawyer

The bash manual lists the syntax for the `for` compound statement as

`for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done`

which implies that the semicolon before **`do`** is optional if the **`in`** clause is omitted. [Note 2].

However, the Posix specification lists only the following three productions for `for_clause`:

```
for_clause       : For name linebreak                            do_group
                 | For name linebreak in          sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group
                 ;
```

For reference, `linebreak` is a possibly-empty sequence of `NEWLINE` while `sequential_sep` is either a semicolon or a `NEWLINE`, possibly followed by a sequence of `NEWLINE`:

```
newline_list     :              NEWLINE
                 | newline_list NEWLINE
                 ;
linebreak        : newline_list
                 | /* empty */
                 ;
separator        : separator_op linebreak
                 | newline_list
                 ;
sequential_sep   : ';' linebreak
                 | newline_list
                 ;
```

As far as I can see, that prohibits the syntax `for foo; do :; done`.

In practice, all the shells I tried (bash, dash, ksh and zsh) accept both `for foo; do :; done` and `for foo do :; done` without complaint, regardless of Posix or their own documentation [Note 3].

Is this an accidental omission in the grammar in the Posix standard, or should the use of the semicolon in that syntax be considered a (commonly-implemented) extension to the standard?

#### Addendum

In the XCU description of the `for loop`, Posix seems to insist on newlines:

> The format for the **for** loop is as follows:
>
> `for name [ in [word ... ]]
>
> do
>
> compound-list
>
> done`

However, in the Rationale volume, it is made clear that the grammar is intended to be the last word:

> The format is shown with generous usage of <newline> characters. See the grammar in XCU Shell Grammar for a precise description of where <newline> and <semicolon> characters can be interchanged.

---

#### Notes

1. Apparently this is the first SO question which pairs [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) and [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer). There is no [idle-curiosity](/questions/tagged/idle-curiosity), which might have been more appropriate.
2. The `bash` manual is not entirely explicit about newlines; what it says is:

   > In most cases a *list* in a command's description may be separated from the rest of the command by one or more newlines, and may be followed by a newline in place of a semicolon.

   That makes it clear that the semicolon preceding **`done`** can be replaced by a newline, but does not seem to mention that the same transformation can be performed on the semicolon preceding **`do`**.
3. Both `ksh` and `zsh` seem to insist that there be either a semicolon or a newline after the `name`, although the implementations don't insist on it.

   The `ksh` manpage lists the syntax as:

   > `for vname [ in word ... ] ;do list ;done`

   (I believe that the semicolon in `;do` and `;done` represents "a semicolon or a newline". I can't find any definite statement to that effect but it is the only way to make sense of the syntax description.)

   The `zsh` manual shows:

   > `for name ... [ in word ... ] term do list done`
   >     where *term* is at least one newline or **;**.

Comment: Notwithstanding the optional newline before `in`, I have always thought of newlines and semicolons as being generally interchangeable in shell scripts. Even to the point of how curly braces are used; `{ :; }` (a no-op) requires the semicolon so that `}` is not treated as an option to the `:`. The opening `{` doesn't have this restriction because its meaning can't be misinterpreted. Incidentally, another inconsistency is that the `sequential_sep` before `do` can includes variety, as long as the `;` comes first. `for s\nin a b;\ndo :\ndone` is valid, but `for s\nin a b\n;do :\ndone` is not.

Comment: @ghoti: The opening `{`, like almost any other bash keyword, is only recognized when it's the first word in a command. One consequence of this fact is that you cannot provide local variable settings as part of a compound command (eg., `foo=3 { a; b; }` must actually be written as `{ foo=3 a; foo=3 b; }`). I'm not convinced that your second observation is an inconsistency, exactly. The separator rule says that a separator is "(a newline or a semicolon) followed by an possibly empty sequence of newlines". So `<newline>;` doesn't work, but then neither does `;;`, for the same reason.

Comment: Ah, okay, that wording was not in your question, I was going by the `sequential_sep` definition you quoted, which appears simply to be either/or, without use of "followed".

Comment: @ghoti. Fair cop. I fixed my description of sequential_sep; the grammar is the part I quoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nicely spotted! I don't have a definite answer, but here is what the source code says about it:

It's indeed not valid in [the original Bourne shell](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/cmd.c) from AT&T UNIX v7:

```
(shell has just read `for name`):
       IF skipnl()==INSYM
       THEN chkword();
        t->forlst=item(0);
        IF wdval!=NL ANDF wdval!=';'
        THEN    synbad();
        FI
        chkpr(wdval); skipnl();
       FI
       chksym(DOSYM|BRSYM);
```

Given this snippet, it does not appear to be a conscious design decision. It's just a side effect of the semicolon being handled as part of the `in` group, which is skipped entirely when there is no "in".

Dash agrees that it's [not valid in Bourne](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/parser.c#n380), but adds it as an extension:

```
        /*
         * Newline or semicolon here is optional (but note
         * that the original Bourne shell only allowed NL).
         */
```

Ksh93 [claims that it's valid](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/ksh93/sh/parse.c#L1240), but says nothing of the context:

```
/* 'for i;do cmd' is valid syntax */
else if(tok==';')
    while((tok=sh_lex(lexp))==NL);
```

Bash has no comment, but [explicitly adds support for this case](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n784):

```
for_command:    FOR WORD newline_list DO compound_list DONE
            {
              $$ = make_for_command ($2, add_string_to_list ("\"$@\"", (WORD_LIST *)NULL), $5, word_lineno[word_top]);
              if (word_top > 0) word_top--;
            }
...
    |   FOR WORD ';' newline_list DO compound_list DONE
            {
              $$ = make_for_command ($2, add_string_to_list ("\"$@\"", (WORD_LIST *)NULL), $6, word_lineno[word_top]);
              if (word_top > 0) word_top--;
            }
```

In zsh, it is's just a [side effect of the parser](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Src/parse.c#L1114):

```
while (tok == SEPER)
    zshlex();
```

where (`SEPER` is [`;` or linefeed](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/b9113980642f37d780d646fcbf4ef90dca69ae3f/Src/lex.c#L311)). Due to this, zsh happily accepts this loop:

```
for foo; ; 
;
; ; ; ; ;
; do echo cow; done
```

To me, this all points to an intentional omission in POSIX, and widely and intentionally supported as an extension.

Comment: Thanks. The archaeological investigation into the original Bourne shell strikes me as highly indicative, but I'll give it a little while longer before accepting, in case some other cyberarchaeologist wanders by.

Comment: The [FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/sh/parser.c?view=markup#l501) and NetBSD `ash` derived shells have, the same comment as `dash`.  The comment appeared in NetBSD's `sh` after [syncing with `4.4BSD-Lite`](https://github.com/IIJ-NetBSD/netbsd-src/commit/8548156fade3606369ff900f5d3b0aca413dbdcc#diff-19ed2b7d4ffdf3b2d0a5c0e793661a93L355), where the it changed from strict POSIX behavior to the current behavior, replacing another comment about not allowing a semi-colon.

Comment: OK. Two little things: First, I don't think that your link is the "original" Bourne shell. [This](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/cmd.c) appears to be "more" original, including the original "make C into a different language" macros. Also the [Posix rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html) is explicit that the System V shell (derived from the Bourne shell) is the basis: "The System V shell was selected as the starting point for the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008."