# bash shell script - list files of certain pattern specified in cmd line arg

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making a generic bash script whose input $1 is file pattern that it wants to iter through. Right now I have

```
for entry in ./$1; do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

but when I run this, I get

```
$ ./stuff.sh PRM*
./PRM.EDTOUT.ZIP
```

although there are many files of pattern PRM*. Is there a way to specify this pattern in the command line args and list correctly all files of the same pattern?

Comment: When you run `./stuff.sh PRM*`, bash will expand the glob and run `./stuff.sh PRM.EDTOUT.ZIP PRM.other.matches.zip`. Your script never sees the pattern, it should just loop over all the arguments (`for entry in "$@"; do ..` or just `for entry; do `)

Comment: Try `./stuff.sh "PRM*"`. You can also change your script to be a single line: `ls $1` but you'll still have to quote your input so it doesn't get expanded before the script gets ahold of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `./stuff.sh PRM*`, `PRM*` is expanded by the shell to the matching files.
If you want to pass the pattern without expansion, then you have to quote it:

```
./stuff.sh 'PRM*'
```

But actually, it will be better to just let the shell expand it (don't quote it, use it as in your example), but change your script to take multiple arguments, like this:

```
for entry; do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

That's right, there is no "in" after `for entry`. None needed.
The `for` loop uses the positional parameters by default in the absence of an "in" clause.
In other words, the above is equivalent to this:

```
for entry in "$@"; do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: One point in favor of passing a quoted pattern: argument length. The command line that results from `./stuff.sh PRM*` is limited in size; if the pattern matches too many files, you'll get a "Argument list too long" error. `bash` built-in commands, like the `for` loop, aren't subject to that limit. Compare `echo {1..100000}` with `/bin/echo {1..100000}` to see the difference. (Depending on your system, a larger upper bound may be sufficient, or you may need to increase it.)

Comment: The correct syntax is `for entry do` without a semi-colon. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896830/is-a-semicolon-prohibited-after-name-in-for-name-do