# arithmetic with xargs input?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have an xargs command:

```
xargs -a es_doc_positions.txt -P 64 -I {} populate_es_index.py --start {} --end {}
```

Is it possible to take the input `{}` and apply simple arithmetic to it? I want to supply the end argument something like:

```
$(({} + 100000 - 1))
```

I haven't had any luck with what I've tried so far.

Comment: you meant `$(( {} + 1000 -1 ))` didn't you? Otherwise, no idea ;-/ . Good luck!

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't work either way.

Comment: Anyhow, why are you using `xargs` in this scenario regardless?

Comment: I'm using its parallel feature to multi-thread the processes.

Comment: Reasonable 'nuff. (Not that you couldn't do that easily enough in native Python too, but this works).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy's solution is excellent, but I couldn't help thinking that the easiest solution would be to modify your python script to take a start and a length rather than a start and an end. That would avoid the extra shell process startup on every task.

Comment: @rici -- an excellent point, and I wholeheartedly agree with its gist; as a minor nitpick, though, it's a shell startup per 16 tasks, unless the OP amends the `-n` value. :)

Comment: @charles: fair enough, I didn't read your answer closely enough. As a counter even-more-minor nitpick, `for arg do` (without the semicolon) is canonical. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896830/is-a-semicolon-prohibited-after-name-in-for-name-do

Comment: @rici -- Just so! I learned something today; thank you!

Comment: The reason I'm not doing this natively in python is because the code I'm using is part of a large codebase that I'm hoping to avoid touching given the risks. Also my python is limited to scripting and trying to navigate that codebase would not be the best use of my time if I can simply apply some external logic to the existing script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` does not invoke a shell unless you tell it to. Thus, it cannot perform shell arithmetic on its own.

Tell `xargs` to invoke a shell, and perform your arithmetic inside that shell:

```
xargs -a es_doc_positions.txt -P 64 -n 16 sh -c '
  for arg do
    ./populate_es_index.py --start "$arg" --end "$(( arg + 100000 - 1 ))"
  done
' _
```

The trailing underscore is a placeholder for `$0`, so values passed by `xargs` into the shell are assigned to `$1` and later.

The `-n` argument controls how many instances each `sh` invocation runs. Lower values will result in fewer unused CPU cycles when you get near the end of your batch of inputs (when fewer than P*n values remain to be processed); higher-value will reduce CPU overhead in starting up shell instances.

<sub>Note that it's very intentional that this solution does not use `-I`. If you wanted to amend it to do so, you'd want to put the placeholder as a final argument, after the `_`, *not* as a substring inside the code; using a placeholder as a substring introduces shell injection vulnerabilities, and also prevents a single shell instance from processing multiple inputs.</sub>

Comment: Very nicely done plus very illustrative and educational.